# MATLAB diff function with matrices of unequal dimensions

Tags: matlab, diff

I read MATLAB diff.m readme, still couldn't figure out the following:

```
    a = [1 2 3]'
    b = [3 2 1 4; 1 1 1 5; 5 5 5 6]
    diff([a b]') = 
    2  -1  2
   -1   0  0
   -1   0  0
    3   4  1
```

what rule is MATLAB applying here? does MATLAB apply different rule if one of the matrices (i.e. a or b) is logical matrix? or both a and b are logical matrix?

Comment: Did you display `[a b]'`? Did that clear things up?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Do you want to compute the difference between the two matrices, as in `a-b`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB applies the same rule regardless of the input matrices. Run your code line-by-line in the command window and see.

`a` and `b` are like this:

```
>> a = [1 2 3]'
a =
     1
     2
     3
>> b = [3 2 1 4; 1 1 1 5; 5 5 5 6]
b =
     3     2     1     4
     1     1     1     5
     5     5     5     6
```

then `[a b]'`:

```
>> [a b]'
ans =
     1     2     3
     3     1     5
     2     1     5
     1     1     5
     4     5     6
```

Now apply the `diff` rule on this as follows:

```
[ row 2 - row 1 ]
[ row 3 - row 2 ]
[ row 4 - row 3 ]
[ row 5 - row 4 ]
```

you will get

```
>> diff([a b]')
ans =
     2    -1     2
    -1     0     0
    -1     0     0
     3     4     1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 
[1
 2
 3]
```

So,

```
[a b] = 
[ 1 3 2 1 4
  2 1 1 1 5
  3 5 5 5 6 ]
```

and thus

```
[a b]' = 
[ 1 2 3
  3 1 5
  2 1 5
  1 1 5
  4 5 6 ]
```

and then diff takes the differences along the first dimension whose size is not 0 (i.e. down each column).
This gives the result

```
diff([a b]') = 
[ 2 -1  2
 -1  0  0
 -1  0  0
  3  4  1 ].
```